# Is there any faster way to export data from oracle table using terminator or terminal in Linux?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing 2 billion records I want to export that data into a CSV file. I have tried in SQL developer to export the data but it's taking too much time and I have to run multiple commands to get desired rows. Is there any faster way to export data using the terminal or any other way to export 2 billion records?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the SQL Developer CLI tool 'sqlcl' to unload data.

```
# fire up the database
docker compose up oracle -d
 
# install
curl -o - https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/java/sqldeveloper/sqlcl-latest.zip | sudo tar -C /usr/local -xf -
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/sqlcl/bin/sqlcl
alias sqlcl='/usr/local/sqlcl/bin/sql'

alias sqlcl
alias sqlcl='/usr/local/sqlcl/bin/sql'

sqlcl app_schema/secret@localhost/XEPDB1


SQLcl: Release 22.3 Production on Tue Nov 22 11:44:11 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

app_schema@XEPDB1> create table demo (x number, y char(1), z varchar2(1000));

Table DEMO created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.022
app_schema@XEPDB1> insert into demo select rownum, 'N', lpad('x', 1000, 'x') from xmltable('1 to 10000');

10,000 rows inserted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.300
app_schema@XEPDB1> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.011
app_schema@XEPDB1> set loadformat csv
app_schema@XEPDB1> unload demo

format csv

column_names on
delimiter ,
enclosures ""
encoding UTF8
row_terminator default

** UNLOAD Start ** at 2022.11.22-11.46.56
Export Separate Files to /Users/USER/code/projects/unload
DATA TABLE DEMO
File Name: /Users/USER/code/projects/unload/DEMO_DATA_TABLE_1.csv
Number of Rows Exported: 10000
Elapsed: 00:00:00.486
Total Elapsed: 00:00:00.491
** UNLOAD End ** at 2022.11.22-11.46.56
app_schema@XEPDB1> !wc -l /Users/USER/code/projects/unload/DEMO_DATA_TABLE_1.csv
10001 /Users/USER/code/projects/unload/DEMO_DATA_TABLE_1.csv

# try with different values to speed up the process.
app_schema@XEPDB1> show arraysize
arraysize 100
```

Best of luck!